# Bash: Nested loops and "Check for change" script

Tags: bash

I'm new to bash scripting and trying to write a basic "check for change" script that will poll a URL every few seconds and compare the results for change. When the page is polled, if the returned HTML contains particular strings, I need it to be continually polled until it doesn't before being compared with the original page. I'm not directly DIFFing the returned HTML because it contains a time stamp and so would always be different. Instead I'm just checking if a string gets removed.

```
#!/bin/bash

URL="http://x.x/x"

for (( ; ; )); do
rm tempnew
rm tempold
mv new.html old.html 2> /dev/null
curl $URL -s > new.html

#----------------------------------------
#need loop here that will check new.html for particular strings and if 
present, keep retrieving page until they're not present before continuing 
script.
#----------------------------------------

grep "search text" new.html > tempnew
grep "search text" old.html > tempold
DIFF_OUTPUT="$(/opt/bin/diff tempnew tempold)"
if [ "0" != "${#DIFF_OUTPUT}" ]; then
echo page changed
sleep 20
fi
done
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is your actual question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop could be something like:

```
while true; do
  grep "particular string" new.html
  if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
    break;
  fi
  curl $URL -s > new.html
done
```

The notation `$?` returns the exit code of the last executed command (which is grep). `grep` returns 0 if a match was found, and 1 if no match was found. Other error codes mean other problems - for example 2 means file not found. Probably you should refine this check, or assure that the file was been downloaded correctly.

If you need to run several checks, then you can substitute the "break" with a block of code which does one more test, and contains a conditional break. For yet another check, again substitute the break with another block of code "if ... then break fi" and so on.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Meeko if so, you should accept the answer. Read the rules and the advices about asking  and answering.